# Making a square move along the screen

Tags: matlab

I am not very good at Matlab and need help for my lab experiments. I need to create a full size image/gif/video? (full monitor size), consisting of a white background and a small black square that moves from left to right. I need to be able later to modify this square size, position and speed. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: You keep saying "I need", but what have you tried?

Comment: You will get a lot more help if you ask a more specific question. Something like "I am trying to accomplish X, here is the code I have written but it doesn't work because of Y". Questions that only consist of "I need to..." but don't contain any code tend to be downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 2):

For this sort of thing, [Psychtoolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/HomePage) is your friend. I don't have experience with it, but it is a MATLAB toolbox perfectly designed for full screen visual stimuli.

The toolbox contains an existing example called '[moving line demo](http://docs.psychtoolbox.org/MovingLineDemo)':

```
MovingLineDemo([xv=10][, twolines=0][, screenid=max])

Shows a pair of vertical lines, or a single line, which travel
horizontally across the display from the left to the right, repeating
infinitely.
```

See if you can edit this to suit your need; if you get stuck, come back to ask a more specific question!